# Validation errors are appearing in the same page on different divs

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page that has a form with a select menu and if there are some validation errors in that form the validation errors are shown using "`@include('includes.errors')`". But in this same page I have a button that when the user clicks in it it shows a modal where the user can introduce a subject, a message to send an email. In this modal I also have "`@include('includes.errors')`".

**Issue:** So the issue is that if there are validation errors in the form in the modal because the subject or messare were not filled by  the user that errors appear on the modal but also on the same page above the form that has the select menu. Also if there are some validation errors in the form that has the select menu and the user opens the modal that validation erros also appear in the modal.

Do you know how to fix the issue?

Form with select menu:

```
@include('includes.errors')

<div class="card">
    <div class="card_body">
        <form method="post"
              action="{{route('conferences.storeQuantities', ['id' => $confernece->id, 'slug' => $conference->slug])}}">

            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                {{ csrf_field() }}

                @foreach($registration_types as $rtype)
                    <li>
                        <span>{{$rtype->name}}</span>
                        <select id="rtype_{{ $rtype->id }}" data-price="{{ $rtype->price }}"
                                name="rtypes[{{ $rtype->name }}]">
                            <option value="">0</option>
                            @for ($i = $rtype->min_participants; $i <= $rtype-> max_participants; $i++)
                                <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
                            @endfor
                        </select>
                        <span>X {{$rtype->presentPrice()}}€</span>
                    </li>
                @endforeach 
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="contactOrganizer" tabindex="-1" 
role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Contact Organizer</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            @include('includes.errors')
                            @if($flash = session('email_sent'))
                                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                    <strong><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></strong>
                                    {{ $flash }}
                                </div>
                            @endif
                            <form method="post"
                                  action="{{route('users.contactOrganizer', ['conference_id' => $conference->id])}}"
                                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {{csrf_field()}}
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('subject') }}"
                                           name="subject"
                                           id="subject">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" value="{{ old('message') }}"
                                              name="message" rows="3"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn" value="Send"/>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery to show the moda if there are validation errors in the contact organizer form:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    @if ($errors->any())
    $('#contactOrganizer').trigger('click');

    @endif

    @if(session('email_sent'))
    $('#contactOrganizer').trigger('click');
    @endif
});
```

The errors.blade.php file:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger mt-3">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li class="text-danger"><strong><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></strong> {{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: You could maybe prefix the errors, and only showing certain pre-fixed errors on the top, and others inside the modal or the other way around. It really depends on how attached you are to 1 blade file showing all errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can acheave what you want using the named message bag like this :

In the controller you have to name your errors like this :

```
function storeQuantities(){ //assuming this is your controller function 
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            // your validation rules here :)
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator, 'conferneceErrors');
        }
}
```

Use the same thing for the other function :

```
function contactOrganizer(){ //assuming this is your controller function 
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            // your validation rules here :)
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator, 'contactErrors');
        }
}
```

In the view you can do this :

```
@include('includes.errors', ['errors' => $errors->conferneceErrors])
```

For the modal :

```
@include('includes.errors', ['errors' => $errors->contactErrors])
```

Comment: Thanks, for example in the contactOrganizer() I have the validation like" $rules = [
            'subject' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required',
        ];


        $customMessages = [
            'subject.required' => 'The field subject is mandatory.',
            'message.required' => 'The field message is mandatory.',
        ];

        $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);"? Do you know if is possible to use that "->withErrors($validator, 'contactErrors');" in this approach?

Comment: Yes it will work you can refer to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#named-error-bags) for more information :)

Comment: Thanks, so it should be something like " $validator =        $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator, 'contactErrors');
        }"?

Comment: Thanks, but its not working properly. For exmaple the user clicks in the button "contact organizer" the modal shows the user click "Send" without fill any field any error apears on modal the errors "The field subject is mandatory" and "The field message is mandatory." appears above the form that has the select menu.

Comment: But works in the case of if the user click in "Next" without select any quantity in the select menu the validation error saying that the user needs to select a quantity appears above the select menu form and on the modal dont appears nothing.

Comment: just to create chat room

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177205/discussion-between-maraboc-and-john).